# How can I use the results of an async function inside useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am dispatching an async function inside my useEffect:

```
  let carts = [];

 useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getOrder(orderID));
  }, []);
```

here is my function

```
export const getOrders = createAsyncThunk("cart/getorders", async () => {
  const response = await axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/techcart/orders/", {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Token ${token}`,
    },
  });
  return response.data;
});
```

I want to use the results of this function and put it an array

```
  order.cart.forEach((element) => {
      carts.push(element);
    });
```

how can i do it after useffect has finished ?

i tried putting it a function inside use effect but it gave the same error
`cart.foreach is not a function`

anyone can help me?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you've asked the same question already. And your code is still equal to `const carts = order.cart`

Comment: You can use `order?.cart?.forEach...` but it's not clear what you are trying to do

Comment: It’s not `useEffect` you want to wait for—it’s the result of the action being dispatched and executed (no clue what you’re using for that). The component needs to handle rendering before the data is available.

Comment: how can i wait for the action to be finished ?
i updated the post with my api call

Comment: Is the dispatch coming from Redux? Where do you try to execute the `order.cart.forEach`? Please help us so we can help you - go to [react.new](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-new?utm_source=dotnew) and maybe put something together.

Comment: by literally doing that. `useEffect(async() => { const result = await dispatch(getOrder(orderID)); ...; setCarts(...); })` (with a `setCarts` call because that `carts = []` should almost certainly not be there, pretty sure that should be a state variable)

Comment: yes the dispatch is coming from an async thunk in cart slice
the `order.cart.forEach` is excuted after the useEffect

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure whether you want this to actually happen *inside* the `useEffect`. If you wish to preserve the result of your api call in a state variable, you can declare:

```
const [orders, setOrders] = useState<Order[]>([]);
```

Then, wrap the `getOrder` method:

```
const getOrderWrapper = async (orderId: string) => {
    const orders = await getOrder(orderId);
    setOrders(orders.cart);
}
```

Then, in your `useEffect`, you can add the following:

```
useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getOrderWrapper(getOrder(orderID)));
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to run `async` code inside `useEffect`, you can do it like this

```
useEffect(() => {
  (async () => {
    const response = await dispatch(....)
  })();
}, [])
```